# How would I know if I were a 1 mm tall robot?

Tags: popular-science, thought-experiment

In the 1955 science fiction short story, [The Tunnel under the World](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tunnel_under_the_World) (SPOILER ALERT) a chemical plant explosion kills all the inhabitants of a town, whose consciousnesses are then uploaded into miniature robots living in a replica town on a table top for the purposes of research into advertising techniques.

How would I know if *my* consciousness had been uploaded into a miniature robot living in a replica town on a table top for the purposes of research into advertising techniques?

What would be the most obvious difference living at the 1 mm scale instead of the 1 m scale? Diffraction effects with my tiny pupils? My experience of the viscosity of the air around me? Regulating my temperature?

Comment: The "wind" would be gale force all day long... dust bunnies the size of tall buildings... nasty looking creatures with six and eight legs trying to eat you... water forming dome shaped pools that evaporate within ten minutes and will suck you in when you try to drink... and let's not forget a loud rumbling noise in your tiny ears. :-)

Comment: ... your eye pupils - sorry, apertures - would be so small you could not see sharp images at all; electrostatic fields would attract you to almost any nonconductive surface around you; your temperature would inevitably equilibrate with the surrounding air; after few weeks the layer of dust in your room would become thick enough to be hard to walk through...

Comment: Should migrate to either SciFi or WorldBuilding

Comment: [Answered on Worldbuilding (click here)](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/40633/how-would-i-know-if-i-were-a-1-mm-tall-robot)